# Get live PayPal application_id for android application

Tags: android, paypal

I tested my android appication via PayPal Mobile Payment Librarie. I used `APP-80W284485P519543T` Sandbox AppId. 
And now I try get live AppId and create Classic API app. As I understand I must upload my .apk for review. How can I do it? I may upload only

> Files must be less than 2 MB. Allowed file types: png pdf jpeg doc jpg
>   docx.

in create application form.

Answer (score 0):

If it's something they're asking for but their upload form won't accept the file size then you could zip it up and place it on your web server, then provide them with a download link.